# Getting net:ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error in React post request within a Flask web app

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, docker-compose, fastapi

I have a multicontainer docker system, where one container is a Flask web application called "ui", and another container is a fastapi app called "briefing".

In my react code in the ui app, I'm trying to sent a post request to the briefing container that looks like this:

```
    const response = await axios.post('http://briefing:8000/process_assignment', formData)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

An attempted post request isn't even logged as having experienced a 404, 500, or any sort of error. I just keep getting this error in my console :
`POST http://briefing:8000/process_assignment net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

I even have a post request working in my http:briefing:8000/process_assignment python function that looks like this, so the docker containers must be setup correctly:

```
    response = requests.post('http://ui:8001/case-brief/api/upload/', json=test_json)
```

Here is the compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  briefing:
    build: 
      context: ../app/briefing/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ../app/briefing:/app/
  ui:
    build:
      context: ../app/ui/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    volumes:
      - ../app/ui:/app/
    depends_on:
      - briefing
```

the dockerfile for briefing:

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.9.17-slim-bullseye

# Set environment variables 
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set the path to the wkhtmltopdf executable as an environment variable
ENV WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash dockerfile_user
USER dockerfile_user

# Specify the FastAPI run command
CMD ["sh", "-c", "cd /app && uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000"]
```

The dockerfile for ui:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Add the Flask app contents into the container at /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

# CMD flask --app aira --debug run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "cd /app && flask --app aira --debug run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001"]
```

Can anyone understand why this isn't working and what I can do to fix this?

I remember the post request working when I first implemented this, and then not working the next day. I don't believe I made any big edits anywhere, but I could've and not remembered. At this point, I've tried to revert back to my original code and implement it to the way I first did it, but its still not working. I've also tried clearing my DNS cache, using the javascript fetch() method of making the post request.

Comment: `briefing` is only available inside your containers, not in your own browser - the names are for inter-container communication

Comment: You'd use `http://localhost:8000` to access the port exposed by the `briefing` container.